# Different behavior when routing packets from localhost addr in IPv4 vs IPv6 case

Tags: linux, networking, routing, ipv6, localhost

Why is IPv4 routing from local address different than IPv6?

Here is an `ip route` example that demonstrates it:

```
# IPv4 case
$ ip route get 1.2.3.4 from 127.0.0.1
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument

# For comparison, IPv4 when source addr is not specified
$ ip route get 1.2.3.4
1.2.3.4 via 192.168.178.1 dev wlp3s0 src 192.168.178.20 uid 1000 
    cache 

# IPv6 case
$ ip route get 1:2:3:4::5 from ::1
1:2:3:4::5 from ::1 via fe80::9a9b:cbff:fe5c:818f dev wlp3s0 proto ra src 2a01:c23:604d:ef00:5e85:b4f4:da92:59f2 metric 20600 pref medium
```

In both cases, we try to route a packet from the loopback IP address (`127.0.0.1`/`::1`) to a public destination (not bound to any local interfaces). IPv4 rightfully rejects the route right off the bat. IPv6 decideds it would route it out through the default GW (and when put to test, *does* send a packet out through the network interface with a src addr of `::1`)

Checking the IPv4 `local` routing table does not show any blackholed routes:

```
$ ip route show table local
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 172.17.0.0 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
local 172.17.0.1 dev docker0 proto kernel scope host src 172.17.0.1 
broadcast 172.17.255.255 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
broadcast 172.18.0.0 dev br-6141a041d1de proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 
local 172.18.0.1 dev br-6141a041d1de proto kernel scope host src 172.18.0.1 
broadcast 172.18.255.255 dev br-6141a041d1de proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 
broadcast 192.168.178.0 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.20 
local 192.168.178.20 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope host src 192.168.178.20 
broadcast 192.168.178.255 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.20
```

What part of the IPv4 stack then is throwing out the fast failure when src is a localhost address?

Comment: I'd say an IPv6 packet with src `::1` sent out on an external interface is a bug, no matter how you look at it. However, I am not sure if the routing is at fault, or if it's something else - IPv4 and IPv6 routing are sufficiently different. Maybe ask on the appropriate kernel mailing list/bug tracker?

Comment: IPv6 packet going out with src `::1` is definitely not useful :) It's playing by the rules though, as I understand them. IPv4 returning an error during `connect()` in the same situation does not follow the rules - or, more likely, I'm missing that special rule it hits.

Comment: The "rules" ([RFC4291](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4291)) say that "The loopback address must not be used as the source address in IPv6
   packets that are sent outside of a single node."